# Copying data from multiple workbooks to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which has two sheets:

'Data Processing' contains a list of cell references as follows:

```
Input Column    Input Row Start Input Row End       Output Column
C               88              105                 A
H               198             215                 B
G               253             270                 C
```

'Results' contains an empty table with headers in row 1.

I want a VBA macro which opens every .xls file in the current folder, and copies data from the first sheet of each one into the 'Results' sheet according to the table of data.

For example, the first workbook should be opened, and the data held in C88:C105 should be copied into column A of 'Results', followed by H198:H215 into row B, followed by G253:G270 into column C.

This should be repeated for each workbook in the folder, the data being inserted into the first blank row (which can be taken as the first blank cell in column A) in the 'Results' sheet.

This is what I have:

```
Sub Consolidate()

Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
Dim originsheet As Worksheet
Dim destsheet As Worksheet
Dim ResultRow As Long
Dim Fname As String


Set destsheet = Workbooks("Consolidate_data.xlsm").Worksheets("Results")

'get list of all files in folder
Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xls")

'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
    Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'find first empty row in destination table
    ResultRow = destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row 

    'start at top of list of cell references and work down until empty cell reached
    Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Processing").Range("A2")

    Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False
        originsheet.Range(ActiveCell.Value & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ":" & ActiveCell.Value & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value).Copy
        destsheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value & ResultRow & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value & (ResultRow + (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value - ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value))).PasteSpecial
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    Workbooks(Fname).Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
    Fname = Dir     'get next file
Loop
End Sub
```

Currently the macro stops at `ResultRow = destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) '.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row` with 'Run time error 1004: Application error or object-defined error'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of starting at the top and using End(xlDown) it's safer to start at the bottom and go up `Resultrow = destsheet.Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row`

Comment: same error on that line though - something more fundamentally wrong with the object reference, I think

Comment: Why do you `Set destsheet` with every iteration of the Do loop if it always points to the same workbook/worksheet combination?

Comment: no good reason. changed.

Comment: @meepmeep: what does this give you `Debug.Print destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)End(xlUp).Address()` ? **NOTE**: there was a typo in my original suggestion

Comment: Does worksheet "Results" contain anything?  If not `destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)` returns column A of the bottom row. `Offset(1,0)` then tries to go down one more row which is impossible and gives error 1004.

Comment: Aha! You've hit the nail on the head. Works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @meepmeep: Tony made a quite thourough answer, I think he deserves that you accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your real problem is that you are trying to do too much in one statement.  This means that neither you nor anyone else can look at your code and see what it is trying to do.  The more complex your code, the longer it takes you to get it right and the longer it will take you to understand it when you have to update it in six months time.  The code below might take marginally longer to run but it is easy to understand and easy to update.

This code is not quite how I would have done but I have tried to follow your style.

Replace:

```
ResultRow = destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

by:

```
ResultRow = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Add the following variables

```
Dim ColDest As String
Dim ColSrc As String
Dim RngDest As String
Dim RngSrc As String
Dim RowInstructCrnt As Long
Dim RowSrcEnd As Long
Dim RowSrcStart As Long
```

Replace your Do loop with:

```
RowInstructCrnt = 2
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Processing")
  Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(RowInstructCrnt, "A"))
    ColSrc = .Cells(RowInstructCrnt, "A")
    RowSrcStart = .Cells(RowInstructCrnt, "B")
    RowSrcEnd = .Cells(RowInstructCrnt, "C")
    ColDest = .Cells(RowInstructCrnt, "D")
    RngSrc = ColSrc & RowSrcStart & ":" & ColSrc & RowSrcEnd
    RngDest = ColDest & ResultRow
    originsheet.Range(RngSrc).Copy
    destsheet.Range(RngDest).PasteSpecial
    RowInstructCrnt = RowInstructCrnt + 1
 Loop
End With
```

Note: not only is each statement of the above code a single step, it does not move the cursor around the worksheet "Data Processing".

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Option Explicit

You should declare **all** your variables. Excel can help you with that if you use the `Option Explicit`.

#### Error origin

In your case :

`destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` returns a `Range`

but you may want `ResultRow` to be a `Long`

You should either use :

**for a Range:**

```
Set ResultRow = destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

**or for a Long:**

```
ResultRow = destsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Comment: My mistake - was meant to be the latter case, I want a Long. Still gives the same error though.

Answer (score 1):

Solution (as in comments above) was the following:

```
ResultRow = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```